# Is a SQL batch better than using a WHERE .. IN() clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to update a bunch of rows if a certain column value matches.

```
UPDATE table_name 
SET column_b = :newValue 
WHERE column_a IN (value1, value2, ... valueN);
```

Is SQL batching an optimal option for this than using the where in clause?

```
@CreateSqlBatch
UPDATE table_name 
SET column_b = :newValue 
WHERE column_a = value1;
```

https://jdbi.org/apidocs/org/jdbi/v3/sqlobject/statement/SqlBatch.html

The query might update from 1 to over thousands of rows. I want it to be optimal when updating at a large scale (thousands of rows).

Comment: Performance wise - Updating one row at a time is bad, Updating all rows at once can be good, updating bunch of rows  is better (optimized). See, the more you touch a table, more IO and so more time consumed for operation. So find optimized solution - either all row at once or in bunch.

Comment: It depends what "SQL batching" does. I guess this is a library that generates one update statement per input item then runs it. This will be slower, but each individual update will be committed.

Comment: In these cases I would even consider a subselect I possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you are updating the same column to the same value for all of the rows, the IN is probably the better direction. I have never had to look at a SQLServer query plan for either option, but I would assume this IN is better since it would probably locate all of the rows in one sweep.

On the other side - while running a batch is quicker than running individual queries, it's still possibly doing multiple table scans (depending on column, index, etc).

Ultimately, you should mock the data/database and just run both to see.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your condition.

Case 1: You want to update same value for particular column for range of numeric condition then you can write:
UPDATE table_Name SET Column_A='ABC' WHERE Column_B BETWEEN 1 AND 20

Case2: If you want to update for different conditional value then you can write
UPDATE table_Name SET Column_A='ABC' WHERE Column_B IN (1,3,6,7)

Case3: If you want to update for only one condition then
UPDATE table_Name SET Column_A='ABC' WHERE Column_B=4